# Remove blank space above and below Google Charts horizontal column chart

Tags: php, javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am show graphs from Google Charts, using a horizontal column chart. I want to remove the blank space above and below the graph.

Here is the code called (some info removed due to NDA):

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        [null, "...","...","...","...","...","...","...","...","Total Average"],
        [null, 100,100,100,100,100,88.89,100,100,98.70]
    ]);

    var options = {
        height: 540,
        title: 'Title here',
        vAxis: { textPosition: 'none', viewWindowMode: 'maximized' },
        colors:["#0B0842","#ADAEAE","#BE3351","#498101","#0D80CA","#A3C116","#91A96B","#E8F72B","#424242"],
        hAxis: { textPosition: 'none', minValue: 0, maxValue: 100 },
        chartArea: { left: 0, width: "78%" },
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

[image: Sample graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space above and below the bars is normally there to separate bar groups when you have multiple rows of data.  If you don't want that space, then you can set the `bar.groupWidth` option in your chart to a larger percentage (up to 100%; default is the golden ratio, roughly 61.8%):

```
var options = {
    height: 540,
    title: 'Title here',
    vAxis: { textPosition: 'none', viewWindowMode: 'maximized' },
    colors:["#0B0842","#ADAEAE","#BE3351","#498101","#0D80CA","#A3C116","#91A96B","#E8F72B","#424242"],
    hAxis: { textPosition: 'none', minValue: 0, maxValue: 100 },
    chartArea: { left: 0, width: "78%" },
    bar: {groupWidth: '100%'}
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted and I've been looking for it in the wrong place. Thanks!

Comment: @asgallant - Hey buddy, I have s similar problem. There are blank spaces above and below all bars, not after each bar.  How can I remove that ? I have posted the question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304413/remove-blank-space-between-google-graph-and-body

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
    var chart_height = data.getNumberOfRows() * 40;
    var options = {
        chartArea: {
            top: 0,
            left: '30%',
            width: '70%',
            bottom: 0
        },
        height: chart_height
    };
```