# Remove blank space below and above google graph?

Tags: javascript, graph, charts

I have used google graph on a particular page after few contents. But as the number of rows(data) in google graph increases, space between content and graph increases. I have tried to modify the height, but no result.

Here is my code -

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Projects');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Hours');
        var monthData = jQuery(".slick-active").html();
        var monthTemp = monthData.toString().split(" ");
        var month = getMonthFromString(monthTemp[0]);
        var year = monthTemp[1];
        var tag = $("#tagVal").val();
        var jsonData = jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/report/additionalProjectHours",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                data: {month: month, year: year, tag:tag},
                beforeSend: function (request) {
                return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='token']").attr('content'));
                },
                error: function () {
                //alert("ERRORRRRRR");
                }
        }).responseText;
        var options;
        var chartHeight;
        if ((jsonData.length) > 134) {

            if (jsonData.length < 200){
                 chartHeight = 250;
            }else{
                chartHeight =jsonData.length ;
            }


            var options = {
                height: chartHeight / 1.3 - 100,
                color: "#0F00FF",
                fontName: "Times-Roman",
                fontSize: 15,
                bold: true,
                series: {
                    0: {
                        visibleInLegend: false
                    }
                },
                bar: {
                    groupWidth: '20%'
                }
            };
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }else {
          $("#chart").html('<p style="margin-right: 70px;font-family: Times-Roman; text-align: center; padding: 20px;">No Data Available</p>');
        }
        $('defs').nextAll("g").eq(1).hide();
   }
```

[image: screen shot of graph]

Answer (score 0):

I expect that your problem is here:

```
chartHeight =jsonData.length ;
```

`jsonData` is a string, so you are setting the height of the chart to be equal to the number of characters in the string. Try setting the height based on the number of rows of data in the DataTable instead:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
options.height = data.getNumberOfRows() * <height per row> + <offset for chart header and footer>;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used various ways to adjust the height, but no result. Even after setting the height manually, it gives same error.

Comment: Which visualization API package(s) are you loading?

Comment: hi asgallant, I have mentioned all code here in my question. I don't know what are you asking about ?

Comment: still no clue. I have given screenshot of graph used on page with the question

Comment: In order to load the Visualization API, you must have a function call somewhere that looks like this: `google.load('visualization', '1.0', {packages:['corechart']});`. I need to know what is in the `packages` array.

Comment: Following is the code --  `(function () {
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
})();`

Comment: The google loader sometimes has issues when running inside other functions. I doubt this will fix your problem, but you should change it to be: `(function () { google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"], callback: drawChart});})();`.

Comment: I don't see anything else that looks obviously wrong, and I cannot replicate your chart because of the AJAX call for the data. Can you create a jsfiddle/codepen/etc example that duplicates the problem?